# trouble adding scrollview in android studio

Tags: android, layout, scrollview

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    >
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/divisionwise"
    tools:context="historical.com.example.ahmed.historicalplacesbd.Division">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/dhaka"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/divisionbtnone"/>
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/chittagong"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/chitta"/>
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/sylhet"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/sylh"/>
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/khulna"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/khuln"
        />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/rajshahi"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/raj"/>
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/barishal"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bari"/>
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/rangpur"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/rangpor"
        />

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I used this code for adding a scrollview in my xml file.but I in my output I get a white screen which takes some place of my  image and buttons. like this.

[image]

now how can I remove the extra blank space that is generated when I emulate my app.i want my image and other attributes to be presented on my app screen

Comment: The LinearLayout inside the ScrollView should have layout_height="wrap_content"

Comment: Just put the scrollview inside linear layout

Comment: Off topic but I would put the buttons in a db driven listview so the app could be easily modified to work with other places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For making image to full screen please use `android:background="@drawable/divisionwise" in scroll view instead of LinearLayout.`

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/divisionwise"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:orientation="vertical"

        tools:context="historical.com.example.ahmed.historicalplacesbd.Division">
    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Maybe adding android:fillViewport="true" in your ScrollView would help. (Instead of setting the background to the ScrollView)

Answer (score 0):

add `scrollview` as a child to container parent `linearlayout`

add like below

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/divisionwise"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="historical.com.example.ahmed.historicalplacesbd.Division" >

<ScrollView
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    >
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/dhaka"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/divisionbtnone"/>
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/chittagong"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/chitta"/>
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/sylhet"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/sylh"/>
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/khulna"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/khuln"
    />
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/rajshahi"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/raj"/>
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/barishal"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bari"/>
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/rangpur"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/rangpor"
    />
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks Karan Mer ..I tried this..but this is generating a rendering problem error.

Comment: for what api you are designing